# How can I increase the space between columns when creating a table in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have made a table in Rmarkdown comparing information about models I have created. Code below:

```
mlist <- list(fitdm3hyp,fitdm3.1,fitdm3.2,fitdm3full,fitdm3.5,fitdm3.5b,fitdm3bi,fitdm3bio)
tablea <- compareLavaan(mlist,fitmeas = c("chisq","df","rmsea.robust","cfi.robust","srmr"),digits=4,type="html",chidif=FALSE)
```

However, the 1st and 2nd columns (chisq and df) end up so close that you can't tell where each value ends and the other begins. It ends up looking like: 343.44160.00   rather than 343.44  | 160.00.

How can I format this to increase the space between columns, please?

Comment: Give us some example data where the effect is visible for us.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Answer (score 1):

You can 'View()' function in dyplr to better view the dataset. make sure you are using a wider window view too. If you use the Tidyverse package, and make it a dataframe, the data should pad itself enough for better visuals.